# how to change the axis tick distance in contour plot in plotly

Tags: python, plot, plotly

plot a contour figure, the range for x axis is large from 0.01 to 100, y axis is from 0 to 15.
such as
`Q_0 = [0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.08, 0.15, 0.4, 1., 5., 10., 20., 50.], w_0 = [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 8.,15].`
the z value I generate is like this code:

```
import numpy as np
Q_0 = [0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.08, 0.15, 0.4, 1., 5., 10., 20., 50.] 
w_0 = [0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 8.,15]

def f(q,w):
  return np.sqrt(q*w)
x = np.zeros([len(Q_0), len(w_0)])
y = np.zeros([len(Q_0), len(w_0)])
z = np.zeros([len(Q_0), len(w_0)])
for i, q in enumerate(Q_0):
  for j,w in enumerate(w_0):
      z[i,j] = (f(q,w))
      x[i,j] = q
      y[i,j] = w
```

Then the contour plot:

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Contour(
        x = x.reshape(-1),
        y = y.reshape(-1),
        z = z.reshape(-1),
        colorscale = 'Blues',
        contours = dict(
            showlabels = True,
            labelfont = dict(
                family = 'Raleway',
                color = 'white'
            )
        ),
        hoverlabel = dict(
            bgcolor = 'white',
            bordercolor = 'black',
            font = dict(
                family = 'Raleway',
                color = 'black'
            )
        )
))
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_title="$Q_0$",
    yaxis_title="$w_0$",
    xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = [i for i in Q_0],
        ticktext = [str(i) for i in Q_0]
    ),
    yaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = [i for i in w_0],
        ticktext = [str(i) for i in w_0]
    )
)
fig.show()
```

and get the figure like this:
[image]

How can I make the axis tick equal distributed similar as label but not by value. for example, 5.0~10.0 has the same distance with 10 to 20, 20 to 50.

Comment: Hi, @BasvanderLinden, have edited it, should be reproducible now, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could force the x-axis to be categorical ([docs](https://plotly.com/python/categorical-axes/)):

```
fig.update_xaxes(type='category')
```

[image: categorical1]

You could also do it for both axes:

```
fig.update_xaxes(type='category')
fig.update_yaxes(type='category')
```

[image: categorical2]